# Unable to push to Remote

Tags: git-extensions

With the basic Git UI I have no problem doing a:
Remote -> Push
To my BitBucket git.

With the Git Extensions I just get a Push to origin dialog with a progress bar (that stays up forever). Message says:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" master:master**

NO errors but no action.

If I configure and load SSH key and click "Test connection"  I get a command window with an error:
**Unable to open connection:
Host does not exist
c:\user\path to my project**

The Url in the dialog is the https connection to my remote account, not sure why its complaining about my local project location.

All other Git Extensions seems to work on my local repository.
I would rather NOT use SSH key and just enter my password as Git UI allows me to do.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with BitBucket. A way to get around this is to use the git bash command line and just commit your changes and push them to the remote server (in your case BitBucket). It will ask you for your BitBucket password but it will NOT show the characters as you are typing. So just type your password and hit Enter.

Sorry if this did not solve your problem just thought it might be helpful

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it answers your question